# Sending Mongoose data to angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose

i need to send data which i can get via a console.log in my node module out to my controller in angular

mongooose code is below, simple i am sure but can not find any clear info online, thank you

```
 var Voltage = mongoose.model('Voltage', {temp: Number});   
  Voltage.find(function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);
   });
```

angular controller is below, i want to send the json which is already saved in the database, out to my controller.

```
var UPSApp = angular.module('UPSApp', []);
UPSApp.controller('UPSController', function($scope,$http, $interval) {

    setInterval(function () {
        $http.get('/solution-two/data2').success(function (data) {
            $scope.users2 = data;
        })
        $http.get('/solution-two/data').success(function (data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        })
    },2000);


    $scope.salesData=[
        {hour: 1,sales: 274}
    ];
    $scope.salesData2=[
        {hour: 1,sales: 333}
    ];
        $interval(function(){
            $http.get('/solution-two/data').success(function (data) {
                var hour=$scope.salesData2.length+1;
                var sales= data;
                $scope.salesData2.push({hour: hour, sales:sales});
            });
            $http.get('/solution-two/data2').success(function (data) {
            var hour=$scope.salesData.length+1;
            var sales= data;
            $scope.salesData.push({hour: hour, sales:sales});
    });
        }, 2000, 60);
})
```

Comment: `Mongoose` is an ORM for MongoDB, you need `express` or some other framework, so that your angularjs code can hit those `endpoints` which would return the data.

Comment: i have express integrated in the stack also, it is the coding aspect of what to do next is where i am stuck. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();
//require the necessary dependencies for your mongoose implementation
app.get('/solution-two/data', function(req, res) {
    var Voltage = mongoose.model('Voltage', {temp: Number});   
    Voltage.find(function(err, data) {
            console.log(data);
            res.status(200).send(data);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

Save that in your server as app.js, make sure you have express installed

```
npm install --save express
```

run it in your console using

```
node app.js
```

and you should be able to receive data from localhost:3000/solution-two/data

Comment: thats great thanks very much guys, that has cleared up things a bit for me wih how it works. the next step is converting it from json to values to my d3.js file. thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

in the following code **you have to send response in json format** instead of **console.log(data);**
if you have installed express frame work you can send response as follow

```
var Voltage = mongoose.model('Voltage', {temp: Number});   
Voltage.find(function(err, data) {
    res.json(data);
});
```